# string concatenate char* with LPCTSTR

Tags: c, character-encoding, strcat

```
LPCTSTR Machine=L"Network\\Value";
char s[100]="Computer\\";
strcat(s,(const char*)Machine); 
printf("%s",s);
```

Here i received output **Computer\N** only i expect output like Computer\Network\Value .
Give Solution for that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to cancat an ANSI string with a Unicode string. That won't work. Either make the fisrt string ANSI

```
LPCSTR Machine="Network\\Value";
```

or convert the second one with MultiByteToWideChar().

Comment: i know but i cannot explore via coding ..if u can tell me solution through coding ..thanks

Comment: You have only two options - if one of the strings is constant (hardcoded) you can just declare it appropriately, otherwise you need to use MultiByteToWideChar() for conversion. The latter is described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606075/how-to-convert-char-to-bstr/606122#606122 except that you can use malloc/free (or better new/delete) instead of SysAllocString/SysFreeString.

Answer (score 3):

The string pointed Machine is a unicode string and hence has one NULL character after the character 'N'. So if you use non-unicode string concatanation you will get the output like that. You should not mix the unicode and non-unicode strings like that. You can do it like this:

```
LPCTSTR Machine=L"Network\\Value";
TCHAR  s[100]=_T("Computer\\");
_tcscat(s,Machine); 
std::wcout<<s;
```

Comment: Is there is any possiblity with only work with strcat without using (TCHAR,_tcscat),if possible ,please respond that in..

Comment: Yes..you can do it as suggested by sharptooth.

Answer (score 0):

Pure C90:

```
wcstombs(s+strlen(s), Machine, sizeof(s)-strlen(s));
```