# c++ Converstion of BSTR Fails

Tags: c++

I want to convert a vector string to BSTR and to V_BSTR but when i debug the output it shows some strange output. Below is the code which am trying.

```
vector<string> v = explode("*", Types);

VARIANT vHeads = { 0 };
BSTR Heads = SysAllocStringByteLen(v[0].c_str(), v[0].size());
V_VT( &vHeads ) = VT_BSTR;
V_BSTR( &vHeads ) = Heads;

char buff[1024];
sprintf_s(buff, "Vhead: %S And Head: %s", vHeads,Heads);
MessageBoxA(NULL, buff, "Debug", MB_OK | MB_ICONQUESTION);
```

The vhead output is some weird output but heads output is as expected.
Can someone say what's wrong?

Comment: `%S` is not the right format specifier for `VARIANT`, and `%s` is not the right format specifier for `BSTR`.  If you use the wrong format specifier you get undefined behaviour.

Comment: @M.M Please mention the right format specifier.

Comment: There is none for Variant, so far as I know.  `%S` is the specifier for `wchar_t`.  But since you used `SysAllocStringByteLen` I think you should write `sprintf_s(buff, "Head: %s", (char *)Heads);` .

Comment: The documentation says `SysAllocStringByteLen` creates a copy of the bytes, with no translation to Unicode. Then treating it as a Unicode string produces garbage. For modern Windows programming just use the basic wide string functions.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Can you show me more clue or example or how may i convert vector string to usable BSTR Value.

Comment: Depends on the encoding of the `string`. Assuming it's ANSI you can use http://stackoverflow.com/a/17066676/464581 Disclaimer: I haven't scrutinized the code.

Comment: `SysAllocStringByteLen` is more intended to be used when transporting binary data via BSTRs

Comment: @M.M. No there is no automatic conversion `string` → `wstring`.

Comment: So someone say me how would i transfer string to bstr actually then.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf error C2664: 'MultiByteToWideChar' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'LPCSTR'.

Comment: @Toe.Pal: `LPCSTR` is Microsoft-speak for `char const*`. If you're using Visual Studio than you can probably just hover the mouse cursor over the word to get a definition. Or "peek definition".

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Your link stackoverflow.com/a/17066676/464581 helped me. thanks. but by adding '.c_str()' to string datat type.