# C++ how to convert a char[] array to _bstr_t?

Tags: c++, bstr-t

I want to convert a `char` `array`, e.g. `char myArray[size]` to a `_bstr_t` string. I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
_bstr_t test;

for (int i = 0; i < myArrayLength; i++) {
    test = test + (_bstr_t) myArray[i];
}
```

Comment: Voting to re-open, since the presumed duplicate is tagged [tag:c]. And since `_bstr_t` is a C++ class, that answer doesn't apply (even if parts of it could be re-used/re-worked to match).

Comment: @IInspectable I disagree.  There is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/606089/4342498) answer which shows how to do it in C++ which answers this question.

Comment: @NathanOliver: That's not the model that SO is looking for: Close a question as a duplicate of another question (asking for a different programming language), and sift through the answers to find the one that doesn't address the question asked, because it, too, uses a programming language that doesn't match the question. Instead, re-open this question, and have an answer here, that addresses the question asked.

Comment: @IInspectable tell that to the users writing Swift answers on Objective-C questions.

Answer (score 0):

The `_bstr_t` class provides a conversion c'tor ([_bstr_t::_bstr_t](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k3ebasf.aspx)) that takes a `const char*`. It performs character conversion from ANSI code page encoding (using the thread's current locale) to UTF-16, and constructs a `_bstr_t` object:

```
 _bstr_t bstr = _bstr_t(myArray);
```

Note, that there is also a binary [_bstr_t::operator+()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21w69x48.aspx), that takes a `const char*` as its left-hand side. The following is also allowed:

```
_bstr_t test;
...
_bstr_t bstr = myArray + test;
```

---

In case your input `char` array uses an encoding other than ASCII or ANSI using the current code page, you will have to manually convert from the source encoding to UTF-16 using [MultiByteToWideChar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072.aspx), and construct a `_bstr_t` from the `wchar_t` array.